# How to replace all characters except for one in a sentence

Tags: python, replace

```py
sentence = “This makes array operations faster but less safe”

letter = ‘a’
```

The function must print

```
******a****a**a******a*******a***************a**
```

I've tried to use the replace and other methods, but I still don't find a way to make it work

```py
spam="This makes array operations faster but less safe"

print(spam.replace("b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z", "*"))
```

I was expecting

```
******a****a**a******a*******a***************a**
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re
sentence = 'This makes array operations faster but less safe'
print(re.sub(r"[^a]", r"*", sentence))
```

**Output:**

```
******a****a**a******a*******a***************a**
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use list comprehension with conditional replacement and then join.

```
sentence = 'This makes array operations faster but less safe'
letter = 'a'

result = ''.join([s if s == letter else '*' for s in sentence])
print(result)
# ******a****a**a******a*******a***************a**
```

Answer (score 1):

This an easy job for `re.sub`, this replace any character that is not `a` to `*`:

```
import re
spam = "This makes array operations faster but less safe"
print(re.sub('[^a]', '*', spam))
```

OUPUT:

```
******a****a**a******a*******a***************a**
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use regex(I know it's simpler), if you want to go with the traditional way, use this:

```py
sentence = “This makes array operations faster but less safe”
result = ''
for letter in sentence:
    if letter != 'a': result += '*'
    else: result += 'a'
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of great answers.  If you need a few more characters you can also use dictionaries:

```
sentence = 'This makes array operations faster but less safe'

filters = {'a': 'a', 'b': 'b'}

result = ''.join(filters.get(x, '*') for x in sentence)

# '******a****a**a******a*******a*****b*********a**'
```